# How to set up multiple onSnapshot() listeners at once

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the react-native-firebase ^3.1.1 and react-native ^0.49.5. A user of my application has variable permissions to territories. For example, User A may have permission to just territory 1, while User B may have permission to territory 1, 2 and 3. When the application starts, I set up snapshot listeners to listen for changes to the documents that correspond to the territories the user has access to. Since there is no logical OR, I have to loop for each territory and set up a snapshot listener like below

```
componentDidMount() {
let { territories } = this.props
territories.forEach(territory => {
  this.unsubscribe.push(
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('dispatches')
      .where('territory_id', '==', territory)
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const dispatches = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(document => {
          dispatches.push(document.data())
        })
        this.props.handleDispatchUpdate(territory, dispatches)
      })
  )
})
}
```

This seems to work but my application 'freezes' when the listeners are being set up. For example, if the user tries to open the side drawer menu or interact with the application in any way, nothing happens for on average about 8 seconds or sometimes up to over a minute, then all the actions seem to happen at once.

I have added console log statements to check if it was due to networking time between the app and firebase like below

```
  componentDidMount() {
let { territories } = this.props
territories.forEach(territory => {
  console.log(`Starting read for territory item ${territories.indexOf(territory)}`, moment().format('hh:mm:ss'))
  this.unsubscribe.push(
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('dispatches')
      .where('territory_id', '==', territory)
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        console.log(`Finished read for territory item ${territories.indexOf(territory)}`, moment().format('hh:mm:ss'))
        const dispatches = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(document => {
          dispatches.push(document.data())
        })
        console.log(
          `Storing documents in redux store for territory item ${territories.indexOf(territory)}`,
          moment().format('hh:mm:ss')
        )
        this.props.handleDispatchUpdate(territory, dispatches)
      })
  )
})
}
```

And the results are below recorded as hh:mm:ss. The user in question had permission to 3 territories

[image]

I am unsure if this is an issue with the react-native-firebase package, firebase firestore itself or an issue with how I am setting up multiple listeners. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem.My idea is,you have different onSnapshot depends on situation with where(),inside both of the function,it triggers another function,it gets the data you need all at once.

Comment: @wizloc did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm running into the same thing in Swift with chat convos/messages.  I can load all the convos, but looping through all of them to add listeners for messages related to each convo is bogging down Firestore for ~20 sec where I can't read/write anything else without waiting for the listener registrations to complete.

Comment: Firestore was pretty fresh in beta at the time of this question if I remember correctly. I ended up switching to real-time database and encountered less issues, of course at the loss of the features that Firestore brings. I can’t say for sure whether that was the definitive fix, but it worked for me and I just haven’t had time to try out Firestore again.